# Mention any user on the server, displaying messages and picture discordjs

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm new with these bot, and I'm trying to mention user with an embed like picture. I've tried this but only sending messages and mention user, not the picture.

```
const { MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'karungin',
    description: 'this is karungin command',
    execute(message, args){
        mention = message.mentions.users.first();
        const attach = new MessageAttachment("karungin.jpg");
        
        message.channel.send(`Hello <@${mention.id}>`, {files: [attach]});
    }
};
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an option object to send your message:

```js
const { MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'karungin',
    description: 'this is karungin command',
    execute(message, args){
        mention = message.mentions.users.first();
        const attach = new MessageAttachment("karungin.jpg");
        
        message.channel.send({content: `Hello <@${mention.id}>`, files: [attach]});
    }
};
```

When specifying a string, only the content is taken into account.

Comment: these one works on me, thanks ! Btw, is it possible to mention user while replying his/her message without using '@' on it ?

Comment: Use reference message option (check the docs at discord.js.org)